# run a python file by calling from php file

Tags: php, python, file, shell-exec

i have a php file through which i am sending variables to python file using:

```
    echo 
shell_exec("C:/xampp/htdocs/Ai_Edutech_trial_project/eclipse_workspace
/Project/dbConn.py '$sess'");
```

it is working fine and but only a very small portion of python file is getting executed. I want execute whole python file for it have code to insert data in db.

This is my python file:

```
    import mysql.connector
    import numpy as np
    import sqlite3
    import sys

    conn= mysql.conector.connect
    (user="root",password="",host="localhost",database="videojs")

    conn_two= sqlite3.connect('videojs')
    c=conn_two.cursor() 


    def read_from_db():

       sess_id=sys.argv[1]
       print(sess_id)

       cursor_one = conn.cursor()
       cursor_one.execute("select time_arr from info where sess_id= '%s'" % 
       (sess_id))
       data=cursor_one.fetchone()
       cursor_two = conn.cursor()
       cursor_two.execute("select type from questions")
       data_two=cursor_two.fetchall()
       str_data_two = ''.join(map(str, data_two))
       split_data_two=str_data_two.replace(")
       ('","").replace("'","").split(',') 
       the_new_list = [x.split(',') for x in data]
       str_data = ''.join(map(str, the_new_list))

       split_data=str_data.replace(" ", "").strip('[]').split(',')
       i = 0
       while i < len(split_data):
         print(split_data[i])   
         i += 1

       #Open the file
       fobj = open("one.srt")
       text = fobj.read().strip().split()
       quo_text= (', '.join("'" + item + "'" for item in text))
       add_list=[]
       i = 0

       while i < len(split_data):
         print(split_data[i])
         if  split_data[i] in quo_text: #string in present in the text file
            print("matched")
            ind_text=text.index(split_data[i].replace("'",""))
            fix_max=ind_text+5
            fix_min=ind_text-5
            while ind_text < fix_max:
                 print(text[ind_text]) 
                 add_list.append(text[ind_text])  
                 ind_text += 1
            while ind_text > fix_min:
                 print(text[ind_text])
                 add_list.append(text[ind_text])    
                 ind_text -= 1 

    else:
            print("not matched" )    
    i += 1 

    database_list=[]
    i = 0
    while i < len(split_data_two):
       print(split_data_two[i])
       if  split_data_two[i] in add_list: #string in present in the text 
           file
            print("matched")
            ind_text=add_list.index(split_data_two[i])
            database_list.append(add_list[ind_text])
       else:
             print("not matched" )    
       i += 1       

       sess= sess_id 
       cursor_three=conn.cursor()
       for elem in database_list:
          cursor_three.execute("INSERT INTO data(sess_id,list) VALUES 
          (%s,%s)",(sess,elem))
       conn.commit()  

       fobj.close()


   read_from_db()
```

But when i pass value from php file only this portion of file is being executed from python file

```
def read_from_db():

  sess_id=sys.argv[1]
  print(sess_id)
```

can someone please help me out..?

Comment: Please fix the indentations

Comment: done sir ... now can you suggest some???

Comment: Looks like a line below `print(sess_id)` is empty one, so definition of the function ends here. remove all empty lines inside `read_from_db`.

Comment: no it didnt worked...

Comment: Have you tried that Python code directly?  If it works, how long does it take.  If it is long to run, PHP might timeout on you.

Comment: no it takes 3 sec max...  any other way cause the code works fine :(

Comment: i dont know i just added a print statment after that

Comment: cursor_one.execute("select time_arr from info where sess_id= '%s'" % 
       (sess_id))

Comment: and the code works fine... woahhhh !